# Create a template in WinForms and use it as a control

Tags: c#, .net, windows, winforms, templates

I'm pretty new to WinForms and I need something for a project: I'm writing a test program for a device. The device sends some data about itself and I have to output some information about it in a tab and on a chart.

Here is the twist: the device can be a double, triple, or n-uple device which means I'll have to output n tabs and n charts.
For this I would like to have a "template" with a tab and a chart and put one for every sub-device, one under another in my winforms window. How do you think is this possible? Do you have a better idea?

I don't know if I'm very clear so I added a picture to explain what I want.(https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nd00g.png)
Thank you

I tried to search the web for templates in winforms but found nothing that fits what I want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, unfortunately windows Forms are based on inheritance.

So you cannot compose new behaviour in, but if you don't mind inheritence,
simply create a child Form
And then use a Panel that will work as your base template, where you can add your chart, and your data.

Then you can either create as many children as you want, one pr type, OR you can compose different behaviour onto the panel, as you like.

I prefer the composing solution myself, as it at least attempts to be modern, but the problem is Forms are not really build for composition, so it would strictly speaking be better to continue in the inheritance paradigm, so everything is uniform.

However, Testing is much harder on inheritance. So I would like composition for that actually. Yes. Composition, is better.

Comment: UI frameworks have used inheritance for decades, with great success.  I think it's fair to say that UI is the "killer app" for inheritance.  Automated testing of UI is overrated.

Comment: And Composition will make your tests smaller, cleaner, and easier to read. And do the same for your code, I am not saying you can't do it, I am saying that I can also drive a car with my feet, but it is still not a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own custom class that inherits `TabPage` and adds whatever child controls you want. Here's an example I wrote some time ago for a tabebed web browser app:

```vb
Public Class WebBrowserTabPage
    Inherits System.Windows.Forms.TabPage
 
    Private _browser As New WebBrowser
 
    Public ReadOnly Property Browser() As WebBrowser
        Get
            Return Me._browser
        End Get
    End Property
 
    Public Sub New()
        Me._browser.Dock = DockStyle.Fill
        Me.Controls.Add(Me._browser)
    End Sub
 
End Class
```

That code is in VB but hopefully the principle is clear. I can provide a C# translation of required. You can then add an instance of that class to a `TabControl` instead of a regular `TabPage`.

If you only need one child control - it sounds like you only need a `Chart` - then you're good to go. If you need multiple child controls then you should probably create a user control with all the children first, then add just an instance of that user control to the custom `TabPage`.

You could also add more functionality by creating a custom `TabControl` if you wanted. I won't go into specifics unless you need them but you can check out my thread on the tabbed web browser [here](https://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?506103-Tabbed-WebBrowser-a-work-in-progress).

Here's a C# translation of the code above, updated a bit too. The original was written almost 15 years ago.

```cs
public class WebBrowserTabPage : TabPage
{
    public WebBrowser Browser { get; } = new WebBrowser { Dock = DockStyle.Fill };

    public WebBrowserTabPage()
    {
        Controls.Add(Browser);
    }
}
```

Comment: This is VB, not C#.

Comment: @MortenBork, if only I'd specifically said that in the answer. Oh look, I did. I copied the code from an old VB project but, as I stated, the principles are exactly the same and I'm even in the process of translating it now that I've finished writing the answer.

Comment: Oh if only you read the tag that said "C#" in the original posters question...
Then you wouldn't have needed to provide an invalid response to an already defined parameter.

I know it's nice to be the first one with a response, but take it easy! No one WANTS to steal your thunder, and your help IS appreciated.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, i'm actually reading your thread on tabbed browser, really nice work ! I can read VB so it's okay you don't have to translate :)

Comment: @MortenBork, except I did read the tag. Why else would I have specifically offered to provide a C# translation? If you think someone has made a mistake then by all means point it out - it will help if they have - but maybe read the answer first so you're not pointing out something that has already been explicitly addressed.

Comment: @jmcilhinney, You read the tag, yet still question if the required response should be in the language required in the original posters question? I am not sure why you are firing back here, if you already knew everything? why did you on purpose, then not initially respond in the language required? 

You purposefully answered the question incorrectly? Only to say you knew, and would provide a proper answer? why all the extra confusion? Just answer correctly? 
Is it me that isn't following something here?

Comment: @MortenBork, *"Is it me that isn't following something here?"*. Yes.